# May I get all references of an object by manual code in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, collections, reference

May I get collection of all references of an object by manual code in c# instead of using find all references in visual studio.

In my case, I want to get collection of all references of variable "Delimiter.Field" by code, not using find all references

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9zew.jpg)

Please help me!

Comment: Yes, by using [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis) for example

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I correctly understood your question. In order to list references to something you need to hover your mouse on it, then `Right click` and then click `Find All References` (in visual studio atleast)

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I want to ask!